# MATLAB doesn't play a loaded .wav file

Tags: matlab, audio

I load couple audio files from a folder with the audioread function as following:

```
for audio_numm = 1:24

    [sound{audio_numm},freq{audio_numm} ] = audioread(strcat('./M_S',int2str(audio_numm),'.wav'));
end
```

It loads without any problem, but when i try to play any of them with the following function:

```
for i=1:24
     sound(sound{i})
end
```

I get the following error:

***Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.***

.wav file is saved in an 1x24 array where each element is another one dimensional array. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: For example sound{1} is 100070x1 double and sound{1,1}  = 9.15527343750000e-05

Comment: `sound` is the name of a build in matlab function, but it seems that is also the name of a variable in your code... not sure it's possible.

Comment: Renamed the sound variable and it worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that a variable is named with a build in function name `sound`.

What [Matlab](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html) says is:

> Avoid creating variables with the same name as a function (such as i, j, mode, char, size, and path). **In general, variable names take precedence over function names.** If you create a variable that uses the name of a function, you sometimes get unexpected results.

So in the for loop, what you expected to be the function is actually the variable `sound`. So it was indexed with non integer values.

You can check if a name is already taken with the command `exists`, it will return zero if the name is not taken:

```
exist toto

ans =

     0
```

Thanks @Brice for correcting me.

Comment: The other way around: the `sound` function has been overloaded with the variable, so Matlab interprets `sound(...)` as acessing the variable. The faulty line of code attempts to access the `sound` cell array at the indices given by `sound{i}` which happen to be a vector of non-integer values. Hence the error message.